# Flow Email Alert does not seem to see recipient

Tags: email, visual-workflow, alert

I have a Flow that calls an Email Alert action to send an email when a status field value changes.  Simple stuff and it works when I (a System Administrator) make the record change but not when another user, also a System Administrator, makes the same change.  Some details:

- In a full data sandbox
- Email Delivery is set to "All emails"
- Both users have the standard System Administrator profile and have access to all data
- I am the recipient on the Email Alert
- The email IS sent successfully if the Email Alert is configured with just an address in the Additional Emails field but NOT when the recipient is specified as a User or a Public Group.  This tells me its not the Flow logic or the message rendering from the associated email template.
- Debug traces show the Flow is called and the sending email action is executed
- Email logs show no email being sent out
- Running debug on the Flow as the other administrator shows no issues
- The Organization-Wide Defaults is configured for "Public Read Only" on Users as Default Internal Access
- Issue exists when the API version of the Flow is 60, 59, and 55.  Did not try other versions.
- From Address on the Email Alert is set to "Current User's email address".
- I have tested with several other users and none of them successfully sent the email either.  Not all were System Administrators.
- The Flow is an AutoLaunched flow configured to trigger when a record is updated.  The entry condition is when a custom field (a picklist) Is Changed.

The issue seems to be the other administrator's account in not able to read the User record of the recipient (me) or at least the email address on that record.  If the other Administrator logs in they can see all user records and all fields on User records.  Been working in Salesforce for 15+ years and this one has me stumped :(

[image: Details of the email Alert]

Here are the results of some tests we performed:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](/tour). Including a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Comment: What type of flow is it? Please [edit] to add details of the flow, its entry conditions and its elements.

Comment: Phil W, I updated the issue to include some info about the Flow.  The Flow does execute fine for all users (I see that in the debug logs).  The condition that results in an Email Alert being called does equate to true and best I can tell from the logs it is called but no email is ever sent (confirmed by getting the email logs).  Also, as I mentioned, if I change the recipient to just an Additional Email (SMTP address) the whole thing works fine for all users.  Its only when the recipient on the Email Alert is a User or a Public Group that the email does not get sent.

Comment: Please use [edit] and show screen shot of Email Alert. Note also you can switch to Send Email action and reference templates in Flow rather than using Email Alert

Comment: @cropredy Maintaining the Send Email action in a flow is very cumbersome when the list of recipients changes frequently and the email alert is used in multiple automations.  I suppose I could create a public Group for every alert and query all the members to get a recipient collection but that seems like a lot of unnecessary work when the Email Alert mechanism is designed to handle all that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue exists ONLY in our full data sandbox org.  We moved everything to production and it worked just fine.  Hope the issue will go away with the next refresh but we are not in a position to do that at the moment so no telling for sure.  Hate to have to test in production but some time you do what you have to do.  In case it is server cluster specific out sandbox is currently on CS172.